# Does the point in polygon algorithm also work with multipolygons with holes?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

I'm currently working on a .net project that involves looking up the coordinates of adresses and checking whether they're in a certain area. The area are downloaded from a WFS service, and is a multipolygon stored as the type `double[][][][]`, the structure is similar to WKT.

I know that a WFS service has a way to check if a point is within the area, but it's checking over 10k adresses at a time, so it needs to be done locally.

This is the code for the method:

```
private static bool CheckIfCoordinatesContainPoint(double[][][][] coordinates, double x, double y)
        {
            
            bool isInsideTotal = false;
            foreach (var polygon in coordinates)
            {
                var isInside = false;

                foreach (var coordinateSubset in polygon)
                {

                    int count = coordinateSubset.Length;
                    for (int i = 0, j = count - 1; i < count; j = i++)
                    {
                        var vertexI = coordinateSubset[i];
                        var vertexJ = coordinateSubset[j];

                        double xi = vertexI[0];
                        double yi = vertexI[1];
                        double xj = vertexJ[0];
                        double yj = vertexJ[1];

                        bool intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
                        if (intersect)
                        {
                            isInside = !isInside;
                        }
                    }

                }


                isInsideTotal = isInside || isInsideTotal;
            }

            return isInsideTotal;
        }
```

I took over this project, so didn't write this myself, but it is, as far as i can see, based on [this](https://observablehq.com/@tmcw/understanding-point-in-polygon) article, but i've adapted it to work with multipolygons.

The problem is that the code works most of the time, but gives wrong answers with the specific multipolyon shown [here](https://wktmap.com/?54499d2d). The polygon is quite messy and complex, but to test it in code you can get geometry from [this api call](https://geoserver.plandata.dk/geoserver/wfs?servicename=wfs&request=getfeature&service=wfs&outputFormat=json&typeName=pdk:theme_pdk_forsyningomraade_vedtaget_v&BBOX=721649,6190955,721650,6190956)

An example of a coordinate that it gets wrong is: x=721649.31 y=6190955.51

This point is very clearly withing one of the polygons, but the code returns false.

My best guess is that the method doesn't support polygons with holes or my adaptation for multipolygons is wrong, but i'm having a bit of difficulty understanding why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw an arbitrary polygon on paper, possibly including holes. Pick an arbitrary point and draw a straight line from the point to the edge of the paper. How many times does the line intersect the polygon border?

If you do this a few times you might observe that for points inside the polygon the number of intersections is odd, and even otherwise. This is called the [Raycast Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) and your code looks like it is an implementation of this, and should support holes just fine.

If you are handling multiple polygons you may need to worry about what is happening for overlapping polygons. Some system considers a point to be "inside" if it is inside *any* polygon, like you have done.

But some systems considers overlaps to be holes, if that is the desired behavior you should remove `isInsideTotal`, and move `var isInside = false;` outside the outer loop, so that you are checking odd/even intersections for all polygons.

If you are working with GIS data you also need to consider things like precision and projections. This can introduce various possible problems. I would suggest drawing your points and polygons yourself without relying on third party sites to verify that your algorithm is correct.

I would also highly recommend introducing some actual types to your code, like a `Point` and `Polygon`. Code like `double[][][][]` makes my eyes bleed.